# ScyllaDB - [Invalid query] message="marshaling error: Milliseconds length exceeds expected (6)"

Tags: cassandra, cql, scylla

I have a table with a column of type timestamp and when I insert a value, Scylla saves it with 3 zeros more.

According to Scylla Documentation (https://docs.scylladb.com/getting-started/types/#timestamps):

> Timestamps can be input in CQL either using their value as an integer, or using a string that represents an ISO 8601 date. For instance, all of the values below are valid timestamp values for Mar 2, 2011, at 04:05:00 AM, GMT:
>
> - 1299038700000
> - '2011-02-03 04:05+0000'
> - '2011-02-03 04:05:00+0000'
> - '2011-02-03 04:05:00.000+0000'
> - '2011-02-03T04:05+0000'
> - '2011-02-03T04:05:00+0000'
> - '2011-02-03T04:05:00.000+0000'

So when I create a table for example:

```
CREATE TABLE callers (phone text, timestamp timestamp, callID text, PRIMARY KEY(phone, timestamp));
```

And insert values into it:

```
INSERT INTO callers (phone, timestamp, callID) VALUES ('6978311845', 1299038700000, '123');
INSERT INTO callers (phone, timestamp, callID) VALUES ('6978311846', '2011-02-03 04:05+0000', '456');
INSERT INTO callers (phone, timestamp, callID) VALUES ('6978311847', '2011-02-03 04:05:00.000+0000', '789');
```

The `SELECT * FROM callers;` will show all timestamps with 3 zeros more after the dot:

```
 phone      | timestamp                       | callid
------------+---------------------------------+--------
 6978311847 | 2011-02-03 04:05:00.000000+0000 |    789
 6978311845 | 2011-03-02 04:05:00.000000+0000 |    123
 6978311846 | 2011-02-03 04:05:00.000000+0000 |    456
```

As a result when I try for example to delete a row:

```
DELETE FROM callers WHERE phone = '6978311845' AND timestamp = '2011-03-02 04:05:00.000000+0000';
```

An error occurs:

```
InvalidRequest: Error from server: code=2200 [Invalid query] message="marshaling error: unable to parse date '2011-03-02 04:05:00.000000+0000': marshaling error: Milliseconds length exceeds expected (6)"
```

How can I store timestamp without getting this error?

Answer (score 3):

You have hr:min:sec.millisec -> Millisec can be up to 999/1000 so essentially that's what the error is saying.

The 3 `INSERT` statement you did are correct in terms of syntax.

The `DELETE` statement should be in the same format as the `INSERT`:

- `AND timestamp = '2011-03-02 04:05:00.00+0000'`
- `AND timestamp = '2011-03-02 04:05:00.000+0000'`
- `AND timestamp = '2011-03-02 04:05:00+0000'`
- `AND timestamp = '2011-03-02 04:05:00'`

The additional `000` that appear in the table are just a display issue.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! It's not just a display issue, it's also a store issue because when I retrieve the value from the database (in the code) I have to remove the 3 zeros and convert it to the initial value so as to make a delete or an update.